# How can I make Ember.js handlebars #each iterate over objects?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to make the `{{#each}}` helper to iterate over an object, like in vanilla handlebars. Unfortunately if I use #each on an object, Ember.js version gives me this error:

`Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed [object Object]`

I wrote this helper in attempt to remedy this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('every', function (context, options) {
  var oArray = [];
  for (var k in context) {
    oArray.push({
      key   : k,
      value : context[k]
    })
  }
  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.each(oArray, options);
});
```

Now, when I attempt to use `{{#every}}`, I get the following error:

`Assertion failed: registerBoundHelper-generated helpers do not support use with Handlebars blocks.`

This seems like a basic feature, and I know I'm probably missing something obvious. Can anyone help?

**Edit**:

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CbV8X/

Answer (score 17):

Use `{{each-in}}` helper. You can use it like like `{{each}}` helper.

Example:

```
{{#each-in modelWhichIsObject as |key value|}}
  `{{key}}`:`{{value}}`
{{/each-in}}
```

[JS Bin demo.](http://jsbin.com/rusevogeda/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 2):

After fiddling with it for a few hours, I came up with this hacky way:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('every', function(context, options) {
  var oArray = [], actualData = this.get(context);

  for (var k in actualData) {
    oArray.push({
      key: k,
      value: actualData[k]
    })
  }

  this.set(context, oArray);
  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.each.apply(this, 
      Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
});
```

I don't know what repercussions `this.set` has, but this seems to work!

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CbV8X/1/

Comment: Unfortunately you're going to run into problems where it won't watch, or update... http://jsfiddle.net/CbV8X/2/

Comment: Is there a way to bind it properly, @kingpin2k?

Comment: unfortunately no, there isn't any built in functionality that says watch all properties on an object, which is what would be required to implement this type of functionality

Answer (score 1):

I've been after similar functionality, and since we're sharing our hacky ways, here's my fiddle for the impatient: http://jsfiddle.net/L6axcob8/1/

This fiddle is based on the one provided by @lxe, with updates by @Kingpin2k, and then myself.

Ember: 1.9.1, Handlebars: 2.0.0, jQuery 2.1.3

---

Here we are adding a helper called `every` which can iterate over objects and arrays.

For example this model:

```
model: function() {
    return {
        properties: {
            foo: 'bar',
            zoo: 'zar'
        }
    };
}
```

can be iterated with the following handlebars template:

```
<ul class="properties">
    {{#every p in properties}}
    <li>{{p.key}} : {{p.value}}</li>
    {{/every}}
</ul>
```

---

`every` helper works by creating an array from the objects keys, and then coordinating changes to Ember by way of an ArrayController. Yeah, hacky. This does however, let us add/remove properties to/from an object provided that object supports observation of the [] property.

In my use case I have an Ember.Object derived class which notifies [] when properties are added/removed. I'd recommend looking at Ember.Set for this functionality, although I see that Set been recently deprecated. As this is slightly out of this questions scope I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader. Here's a tip: setUnknownProperty

---

To be notified of property changes we wrap non-object values in what I've called a *DataValueObserver* which sets up (currently one way) bindings. These bindings provide a bridge between the values held by our internal ArrayController and the object we are observing.

When dealing with objects; we wrap those in ObjectProxy's so that we can introduce a 'key' member without the need to modify the object itself. Why yes, this does imply that you could use #every recursively. Another exercise for the reader ;-)

I'd recommend having your model be based around Ember.Object to be consistent with the rest of Ember, allowing you to manipulate your model via its get & set handlers. Alternatively, as demonstrated in the fiddle, you can use Em.Get/Em.set to access models, as long as you are consistent in doing so. If you touch your model directly (no get/set), then `every` won't be notified of your change.

```
Em.set(model.properties, 'foo', 'asdfsdf');
```

---

For completeness here's my `every` helper:

```
var DataValueObserver = Ember.Object.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        // one way binding (for now)
        Em.addObserver(this.parent, this.key, this, 'valueChanged');
    },
    value: function() {
        return Em.get(this.parent, this.key);
    }.property(),
    valueChanged: function() {
        this.notifyPropertyChange('value');
    }
});

Handlebars.registerHelper("every", function() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    var options = args.pop();
    var context = (options.contexts && options.contexts[0]) || this;

    Ember.assert("Must be in the form #every foo in bar ", 3 == args.length && args[1] === "in");
    options.hash.keyword = args[0];
    var property = args[2];

    // if we're dealing with an array we can just forward onto the collection helper directly
    var p = this.get(property);
    if (Ember.Array.detect(p)) {
        options.hash.dataSource = p;
        return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.collection.call(this, Ember.Handlebars.EachView, options);
    }

    // create an array that we will manage with content
    var array = Em.ArrayController.create();
    options.hash.dataSource = array;
    Ember.Handlebars.helpers.collection.call(this, Ember.Handlebars.EachView, options);

    //
    var update_array = function(result) {
        if (!result) {
            array.clear();
            return;
        }

        // check for proxy object
        var result = (result.isProxy && result.content) ? result.content : result;
        var items = result;

        var keys = Ember.keys(items).sort();

        // iterate through sorted array, inserting & removing any mismatches
        var i = 0;
        for ( ; i < keys.length; ++i) {
            var key = keys[i];
            var value = items[key];
            while (true) {
                var old_obj = array.objectAt(i);
                if (old_obj) {
                    Ember.assert("Assume that all objects in our array have a key", undefined !== old_obj.key);
                    var c = key.localeCompare(old_obj.key);
                    if (0 === c) break; // already exists
                    if (c < 0) {
                        array.removeAt(i); // remove as no longer exists
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                // insert
                if (typeof value === 'object') {
                    // wrap object so we can give it a key
                    value = Ember.ObjectProxy.create({
                        content: value,
                        isProxy: true,
                        key: key
                    });
                    array.insertAt(i, value);
                } else {
                    // wrap raw value so we can give it a key and observe when it changes
                    value = DataValueObserver.create({
                        parent: result,
                        key: key,
                    });
                    array.insertAt(i, value);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        // remove any trailing items
        while (array.objectAt(i)) array.removeAt(i);
    };

    var should_display = function() {
        return true;
    };

    // use bind helper to call update_array if the contents of property changes
    var child_properties = ["[]"];
    var preserve_context = true;
    return Ember.Handlebars.bind.call(context, property, options, preserve_context, should_display, update_array, child_properties);
});
```

Inspired by:

- [How can I make Ember.js handlebars #each iterate over objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738047/how-can-i-make-ember-js-handlebars-each-iterate-over-objects)
- http://mozmonkey.com/2014/03/ember-getting-the-index-in-each-loops/
- https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4365
- https://gist.github.com/strathmeyer/1371586

Here's that fiddle again if you missed it:

- http://jsfiddle.net/L6axcob8/1/